# Googl ASR integration using UniMRCP for two way communication

Tags: asterisk, dialplan, unimrcp

I wanted to capture all the voice conversation between customer and agent in text format.

I have done the integration with **Asterisk** and **Google Speach-to-Text** using **UniMRCP**. I'm successfully able to capture customer side speech only but I wanted to captured agent's conversation too.

Sample dialplan:

```
exten => s,1,Answer()

exten => s,2,Originate(SIP/101,exten,google,s,3)

exten => s,3,SpeechCreate()

exten => s,4,SpeechActivateGrammar(builtin:speech/transcribe)

exten => s,5,SpeechBackground(beep, 20)

exten => s,6,Verbose(1, "Recognition result count: ${SPEECH(results)}")

exten => s,7,GotoIf($["${SPEECH(results)}" = "0"]?7:9)

exten => s,8,Playback(error)

exten => s,9,Goto(3)

exten => s,10,Verbose(1, "Recognition result: ${SPEECH_TEXT(0)}, confidence score: ${SPEECH_SCORE(0)}, grammar-uri: ${SPEECH_GRAMMAR(0)}")

exten => s,11,SpeechDestroy()
```

I want to save both parties communication in a text format need suggestion on dialplan part to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way - send both parties to conference(see n-way-calling howto) and listen to conference.

You also  can use ChanSpy

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but is this possible speech recolonization of all parties,online in a conference bridge(using UniMRCP).
Could please help me with some more details with the call flow or Dialplan.
Today I have tried below dialplan but I can only able to recognize the voice of the callee.

[testing]

exten => 1,1,NoOp()
 same => n,Dial(SIP/100,,U(google^arg1))
 same => n,Hangup()

[google]

exten => s,1,Answer()

exten => s,2,MRCPRecog("builtin:speech/transcribe", spl=en-US&f=beep&p=uni2)

exten => s,3,Verbose(Status: ${RECOGSTATUS} Result: ${RECOG_RESULT})

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Sorry, i am not going do your work for you.